# QThread and pyqtgraph no performance improvement

Tags: python-2.7, qthread, pyqtgraph

I am trying to do a multigraph window for plotting different data using pyqtgraph. I have a working version with no threads using timers for getting the data. I also tried a threaded version but it seems to have no performance boost when use htop for visually inspecting the CPU Usage.

I am new to GUIs and Threads so I followed this code that I saw in a youtube tutorial. It uses a QThread to get the CPU usage using `psutil.cpu_percent` in intervals of 0.1 seconds and then updates a progress bar.

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore
from PyQt4 import QtGui
import progress
import sysinfo

class MainUIClass(QtGui.QMainWindow, progress.Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(MainUIClass, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.threadClass = ThreadClass()
        self.threadClass.start()
        self.connect(self.threadClass, QtCore.SIGNAL('CPU_VALUE'),
                     self.updateProgressBar)

    def updateProgressBar(self, val):
        self.progressBar.setValue(val)


class ThreadClass(QtCore.QThread):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(ThreadClass, self).__init__(parent)

    def run(self):
        while 1:
            val = sysinfo.getCPU()
            self.emit(QtCore.SIGNAL('CPU_VALUE'), val)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app = MainUIClass()
    app.show()
    a.exec_()
```

I tried using cProfile for comparing performance but it throws lot of stuff that couldn't read, so I use the example of the progress bar to average the cpu usage after 10 seconds. Sorry if my measure performance method is so poor.

My two codes for benchmarking are

Threaded Version with a very consistent average CPU Usage of 64%:

```
import sys
from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtCore
from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtGui
import pyqtgraph as pg
import numpy as np
import time 

class GraphWindow_Thread(pg.GraphicsWindow):
    def __init__(self, rows, cols, titles):
        super(GraphWindow_Thread, self).__init__()

        # Code to draw the GUI
        self.rows = rows
        self.cols = cols
        self.titles = titles
        self.plots = [] # List of PlotItems
        self.curves = [] # List of PlotDataItems in each PlotItem

        for i in range(self.rows):
            for j in range(self.cols):
                p = self.addPlot()
                self.plots.append(p)
                if titles != [] or len(titles) == 1:
                    p.setLabel('left', self.titles[i+j+1])
                p.setDownsampling(mode='peak')
                p.setClipToView(True)
                pp = p.plot(pen=(155, 255, 50))
                pp1 = p.plot(pen=(55, 130, 255))
                self.curves.append((pp, pp1))
            self.nextRow()

        # Thread to get the data and redraw plots
        self.thread_graph = DataThread()
        self.thread_graph.start()
        self.connect(self.thread_graph, QtCore.SIGNAL('DATA_VALUE'),
                     self.update_plots)

    def set_titles(self, titles):
        for i, p in enumerate(self.plots):
            p.setLabel('left', titles[i])

    def update_plots(self, data, dataD):
        for curve in self.curves:
            curve[0].setData(data)
            curve[1].setData(dataD)


class DataThread(QtCore.QThread):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(DataThread, self).__init__(parent)

    def run(self):
        while 1:
            data = np.random.random((30,))
            dataD = np.random.random((30,))
            self.emit(QtCore.SIGNAL('DATA_VALUE'), data, dataD)
            time.sleep(.1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    gui = GraphWindow_Thread(2,3,[])
    gui.show()
    app.exec_()
```

No Thread Version with a very consistent average CPU Usage of 65%:

```
import sys
from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtCore
from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtGui
import pyqtgraph as pg
import numpy as np
import time 

class GraphWindow(pg.GraphicsWindow):
    def __init__(self, rows, cols, titles):
        super(GraphWindow, self).__init__()

        # Code to draw the GUI
        self.rows = rows
        self.cols = cols
        self.titles = titles
        self.plots = [] # List of PlotItems
        self.curves = [] # List of PlotDataItems in each PlotItem

        for i in range(self.rows):
            for j in range(self.cols):
                p = self.addPlot()
                self.plots.append(p)
                if titles != [] or len(titles) == 1:
                    p.setLabel('left', self.titles[i+j+1])
                p.setDownsampling(mode='peak')
                p.setClipToView(True)
                pp = p.plot(pen=(155, 255, 50))
                pp1 = p.plot(pen=(55, 130, 255))
                self.curves.append((pp, pp1))
            self.nextRow()

        # Timer to redraw plots
        timer = QtCore.QTimer(self)
        self.connect(timer, QtCore.SIGNAL('timeout()'),self.update_plots)
        timer.start(100)

    def set_titles(self, titles):
        for i, p in enumerate(self.plots):
            p.setLabel('left', titles[i])

    def update_plots(self):
        np.random.seed()
        data = np.random.random((30,))
        dataD = np.random.random((30,))
        for curve in self.curves:
            curve[0].setData(data)
            curve[1].setData(dataD)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    gui = GraphWindow(2,3,[])
    gui.show()
    app.exec_()
```

The full app is meant to be a window with multiple tabs, each one with a GraphWindow in which each graph uses a Thread for plotting different data.

What am I missing? Why my threaded version does not represent a performance improvement?

Comment: give it a delay inside the `while True:`  for example `time.sleep(0.1)`

Comment: I already did. Look at the DataThread run function. I can increase the delay for improving performance but I don't want the plots refresh to look slow.

Comment: I would recommend only emitting the signal when the current value is different from the previous one, so the window is not refreshed unnecessarily.

Comment: Thanks, I can do that but the data I want to display changes very fast over time so I'm not sure it will make an important improvement.  My question is more about why the use of QThread seems to make no big difference.

Comment: Using a new thread does not imply performance improvement, only the main thread will not see that load.

Comment: Mmmmm I get it. I think I'm confused on what Threads can offer me. Any tips, articles or blogs you can recommend me to improve performance?
Cause when I run the full app my CPU usage is over 90% and my computer has a noticeable slow down.

Comment: For me your application does not consume almost any resources. What device are you testing it on? Have you tested each function you use, would it be good to identify what is the bottleneck?

Comment: I suggest you read about the Python GIL. Threads in Python only  really help if your task is IO bound. By definition you're benchmark assumes a CPU bound task, so you see no speedup. The real question is where you plan to get your data from and whether that operation takes time (is IO bound).